# how to accept multiple parameters from returning function in groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to return multiple values from a function written in groovy and receive them , but i am getting an error

> class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ListExpression, with its value '[a,
>   b]', is a bad expression as the left hand side of an assignment
>   operator

My code is

```
int a=10
int b=0
println "a is ${a} , b is ${b}"
[a,b]=f1(a)
println "a is NOW ${a} , b is NOW ${b}"

def f1(int x) {   
  return [a*10,a*20]
}
```

Comment: Helpful link on how to return multiple values for different programming languages https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Return_multiple_values#Groovy

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You almost have it. Conceptually `[ a, b ]` creates a list, and `( a, b )` unwraps one, so you want `(a,b)=f1(a)` instead of `[a,b]=f1(a)`.

```
int a=10
int b=0
println "a is ${a} , b is ${b}"
(a,b)=f1(a)
println "a is NOW ${a} , b is NOW ${b}"

def f1(int x) {
    return [x*10,x*20]
}
```

Another example returning objects, which don't need to be the same type:

```
final Date foo
final String bar
(foo, bar) = baz()
println foo
println bar

def baz() {
    return [ new Date(0), 'Test' ]
}
```

Additionally you can combine the declaration and assignment:

```
final def (Date foo, String bar) = baz()
println foo
println bar

def baz() {
    return [ new Date(0), 'Test' ]
}
```

Comment: Added a line to the answer to highlight the change the OP needed to make since different brackets in 8 lines of code can be easily missed.

Comment: If the return types are object, then what will happen? Can anyone explain please. I want to return multiple object from a method.

Comment: It's pretty much the same. I'll add an example with dates.

Comment: The more technically correct and common term for what Justin wrote above as "unwraps" is "destructuring"; in this case, the calling statements are destructuring assignment statements.  See [1.2.1. Multiple assignment](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_multiple_assignment) for details.

Answer (score 48):

You can declare and assign the variables in which the return values are stored in one line like this, which is a slightly more compact syntax than that used in Justin's answer:

```
def (int a, int b) = f1(22)
```

In your particular case you may not be able to use this because one of the variables passed to `f1` is also used to store a return value

Comment: According to [Groovy Goodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2009/09/groovy-goodness-multiple-assignments.html) you don't even need the `int` declarations inside the parentheses.

Comment: @sschuberth True, but you might want it if you want the static type checking/coercion that comes with declaring types

Answer (score 6):

When running Groovy in the context of Jenkins pipeline job the above answers do not work (at least on version 2.60.2), but the following does:

```
node {
    obj = ret2()
    fw = obj[0]
    lw = obj[1]
    echo "fw=${fw}"
    echo "lw=${lw}"
}

def ret2()
{
    return [5, 7]
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
node {
    obj = ret2()
    fw = obj.a
    lw = obj.b
    echo "fw=${fw}"
    echo "lw=${lw}"
}

def ret2()
{
    return [a:5, b:7]
}
```