# Why can't I directly assign to object properties using multiple return values from a method?

Tags: groovy, return, return-value

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6757539/1075499) question I've coded the following which throws a compilation time error:

**Here is the code:**

```
43. Currency currency = new Currency()
44. (currency.rate_one, currency.time_one) = getDateAndRate()
```

**My method with two return values:**

```
def getDateAndRate(){
    Date date = new Date()
    double rate = getRate();
    return [rate, date]
}
```

**Error thrown**

```
expecting '}', found ',' @ line 44, column 26.
(currency.rate_one, currency.time_one) = getDateAndRate()
                  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
def (rate, time) = getDateAndRate()
currency.rate_one = rate
currency.time_one = time
```

Comment: It works! but why on earth it doesn't work like above? So annoying

Comment: if you want to make this code less verbose you could change `getDateAndRate` to accept a `Currency` argument, update it within the method, and return it

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick I learned only recently myself and that is to combine multiple assignment and with:

```
with (currency) {
    (rate_one, time_one) = getDateAndTime()
}
```